# C#: Create/Insert Excel 2007 charts into Word 2007

Tags: c#, charts, excel-2007, office-interop, word-2007

How do you create and then insert an Excel 2007 chart in Word 2007 with office interoperability?

Important: I do not want to save an Excel file to create a chart.

Comment: `create a Word 2007 chart by using Excel 2007`? I assume you meant create Excel 2007 chart and insert it into Word 2007 doc, yea?